# How to get specific lines in yaml files

Tags: java, yaml

I'm currently working on a java game and i wanted to know how to get specific lines in Y A M L files so i can make options that the user can choose from and that can be saved

i have tried to use a Output Stream and a Input Stream but it hasn't worked

here are my class and yes i started out recently

Main:

```
package zoomingEngine;

import zoomingEngine.displayEngine.DisplayManager;

public class Main {

    // Main Variables
    DisplayManager dman = new DisplayManager();
}
```

DisplayManager:

```
package zoomingEngine.displayEngine;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import zoomingEngine.loadEngine.optionsYamlClass;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DisplayManager extends JFrame {

    // DisplayManager Variables
    File optionsYaml = new File("Recourses\\YML\\Options.yml");
    Container cp = getContentPane();
    optionsYamlClass oyc = new optionsYamlClass();

    public void createDisplay() {

   }
}
```

Comment: Which specific lines do you need? Why not read the whole file?

Comment: Are you using a proper YAML parser? Why can't you just have the whole thing read as a set of `Map`s or nice type-safe container class? Just picking out individual lines seems inappropriate and unwise for YAML, just as it would be for JSON or XML. https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation

Comment: well is there any other format type that i can use?

Comment: YAML is a really nice format, I recommend. Just don't reinvent the wheel trying to read/write it yourself. I've only ever used it read-only with SnakeYAML, but you should check out what the existing tools/libs already do.

Comment: `Recourses` -> `Resourses`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist `Resourses` -> `Resources`?

Comment: @m0skit0. Yes. It is a two-step transformation :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Makes sense. You are a mad scientist after all.